# Batch running of clogit in R using lapply

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I am trying to run conditional logistic regression using survival{clogit} in R. As I have about 300 features in my dataset to regress against I am trying to run clogit in a loop. But it seems clogit doesn't run when I use it in lapply by varying the feature in every iteration. An example is below:

```
intervention<-c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
match_id<-c(10019,10019,10026,10026,10051,10051,10155,10155,10156,10156,10191,10191,10276,10276,10352,10352,10398,10398,10448,10448)
AAA<-c(0.561882338,0.590773332,0.280532865,0.28826806,0.33906137,0.242355092,0.340010932,0.352662714,0.324693609,0.322127852,0.338397267,0.697613063,0.363248497,0.391860659,0.374711683,0.366319323,0.335986428,0.390359798,0.492056527,0.652158866)
BBB<-c(0.069485923,0.067290724,0.030931896,0.032030524,0.047487704,0.041788871,0.04246649,0.034830486,0.02499338,0.03231839,0.033805974,0.074300373,0.051343724,0.04842683,0.040587732,0.041552691,0.026273574,0.034315159,0.063913729,0.065222581)

df_clogit<-data.frame(intervention,match_id,AAA,BBB)

IV<-colnames(df_clogit)[3:dim(df_clogit)[2]] 
DV<-colnames(df_clogit)[1]

my.clogit.formula <- lapply(IV, function(var) {paste(DV,"~",var," +   strata(match_id)")})
listcLogitOut<-lapply(my.clogit.formula, function(f) clogit(f,df_clogit))
```

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

```
my.clogit.formula <- lapply(IV, function(var) {paste(DV,"~",var," + strata(match_id),data=df_clogit")})
listcLogitOut<-lapply(my.clogit.formula, function(f) clogit(f))
```

> Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
>   :1:39: unexpected ','

However, if I take an element of the my.clogit.formula and run it out side the lapply it works!

```
clogit(intervention ~ BBB  + strata(match_id),data=df_clogit)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there an alternative to running clogit from within lapply or using any of the apply functions?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use formula as parameter for clogit

```
   listcLogitOut<-lapply(my.clogit.formula, function(f) clogit(as.formula(f),data=df_clogit))
```